Is there a way to loop a formula in google sheets?
Currently I have this working formula in google sheets
=SUMPRODUCT(
  (IMPORTRANGE(Data!$B$1, $B$1 & "!C6:C9")=$B6) * (IMPORTRANGE(Data!$B$1, $B$1 & "!D5:AH5")=D$5) * IMPORTRANGE(Data!$B$1, $B$1 & "!D6:AH9")
  +
  (IMPORTRANGE(Data!$B$2, $B$1 & "!C6:C9")=$B6) * (IMPORTRANGE(Data!$B$2, $B$1 & "!D5:AH5")=D$5) * IMPORTRANGE(Data!$B$2, $B$1 & "!D6:AH9")
)

As you can see, it has repeating part, which I need to extend to the range Data!$B$1:$B$100
Of course, I can manualy input the repeating part and change Data!$B$1 to Data!$B$3,Data!$B$4 and so on. But I am wondering if it is possible to make it loop?

$B$1 - things which will be constant when formula applied to new range.
$B1 - change row
B$1 change column
B1 - change both
Hopefully it will help.

$B$1 Is a name of sheet. Data!$B$1 is a link. If I extent it to the rest of cells, it will do exactly what I want. I cant get rid of any $ in it.


Here's one generalized approach using reduce():
=reduce(,tocol(Data!$B$1:$B$100,1),lambda(a,c,let(Σ,importrange(c,$B$1&"!C5:AH9"),a+filter(filter(Σ,chooserows(Σ,1)=D$5),choosecols(Σ,1)=$B6))))

**Untested since no testing ground sheets provided

Thank you. I had to rework your formula, so now it works as intended. because it broke every time if the value was missing.
=REDUCE(0; TOCOL(Data!$B$1:$B$100; 1);
LAMBDA(a; c;
LET(
Σ; IMPORTRANGE(c; $B$1 & "!C5:AH9");
a + IFERROR(
FILTER(FILTER(Σ; CHOOSEROWS(Σ; 1) = D$5); CHOOSECOLS(Σ; 1) = $B6);
0
)
)
)
)
